# Posting selected array to new php page?

Tags: php, arrays, string, post, session-variables

I am working posting the selected item from my array list to a new php page. However, I have place session to test if session is working. So far it is. However, I am unable to think of a way to obtain the selected array to a new page.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <title>Pizza Orders</title>
     <!--

     -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: bisque
}

.formLayout {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: solid 1px #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 115px;
}

.formLayout label, .formLayout input {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.formLayout label {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#cmdSubmit {
    margin: 0 100px;
}

.example {
    font-family: monospace;
    color: green;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.phpEcho {
    background-color: orange;
    border: thin black solid;
    padding: 25px;
}

br {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Pizza Orders</h2>
<div class="phpEcho">
<?php



// build the multidimensional array
$arrCustInvoices = array
    (
        array("02/28 8:30 p.m.", "Small, hand tossed: MeatLovers: pepperoni, sausage, hamburger", 16.55, 1.55, 18.10, "Robert Elias", "400 w. 10th, Anaheim", "<input action=\"Post\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" id=\"checkbox\">"),
        array("02/28 8:43 p.m.", "Large, hand tossed: Veggie: onion, mushroom, tomatoe", 11.55, 1.25, 12.80, "Bob Harper", "123 w. main st., Anaheim", "<input action=\"Post\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" id=\"checkbox\">"),
        array("02/28 8:51 p.m.", "Medium, Deep Dish: Build Your Own: pepperoni, tomatoe", 13.55, 1.35, 14.90, "Frank Lopez", "385 n. Salute ave, Tustin", "<input action=\"Post\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" id=\"checkbox\">"),
    );
// count the number of indexes in the multidimensional array
$intNumIndexes = count($arrCustInvoices);

// create a count for the number of invoices pulled
$intCount = 0;

print "<h3>Undelivered Pizzas</h3>";
print "<table border=\"1\" padding=\"10px\" width=\"90%\">";
print "<tr>";
print "<th>Item Number</th><th>Date/Time</th><th>Pizza Type</th><th>Price</th><th>Tax</th><th>Total</th>"
. "<th>Customer Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Delivered</th>";
print "</tr>";

// use the for to loop through the indexes
for ($i = 0; $i < $intNumIndexes; $i++){
    // create a row for each invoice
    echo "<tr>";
    // indexes start at 0, so up the count by 1 to display a logical number in the table
    $intItem = $i + 1;

    // display the item number
    echo "<td align=\"center\">$intItem</td>";

    // loop through each of the multidimensional array indexes and display them in a table cell
    for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++){
        echo "<td align=\"center\">";
        echo $arrCustInvoices[$i][$j];
        echo "</td>";
    }

    // close the row
    echo "</tr>";

    // up the count for summary purposes
    $intCount++;
}
//$arrCustInvoices = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "checked");
//$result = $arrCustInvoices[$arrCustInvoices];
// display the count for summary


$_SESSION['session_var'] = "testing";

echo "<form method=\"POST\" action='completeOrder.php'><tr><td colspan=\"10\" align=\"center\"><input type='submit' value='Selected Pizzas Delivered'></form></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"10\" align=\"right\">Total Number of Invoices: " . $intCount . "</td></tr>";

?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here. So far you are not submiting any data inside the form. For more info on sessions see the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: I am trying to assign the multidimensional initial key to the checkbox value within the array. Is there a way to that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to assign the multidimensional initial key to the checkbox value within the array, add the second line into your first for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrCustInvoices); $i++){
    $arrCustInvoices[$i][7] = "<input action=\"Post\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$i."\" id=\"checkbox\">";
}
```

That line will rewrite the input tag string and add's the iterator in it.